# Anyway to debug Nvidia OpenCL on Linux system

Tags: debugging, opencl, nvidia

I wonder if there is any way to debug OpenCL with Nvidia device on Linux system. I knew Nsight Visual Studio could debug OpenCL, but that seems only work on Windows. Also, Nvidia Visual Profiler seems only work with CUDA.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The question was asked before    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265560/how-to-debug-opencl-on-nvidia-gpus

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot debug OpenCL on NVidia with NSight, as it does not provide OpenCL debugger, you can debug CUDA though. I personally could not find a way to debug OpenCL on NVidia card. OpenCL debugs just fine with AMD tools, AMD hardware for sure, CodeXL. Also, I could find drivers for me to run OpenCL 2.0 by AMD, but only 1.2 by NVidia.